# switch nginx php version for some websites

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, fpm, laravel-forge

I have digitalocean server and I manage it by laravel forge. The server configured with php7.3 an it is ok. I wanna use for some websites php5.6 and for some websites php7.3. So I want somehow switch php version in the nginx configuration.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

> I changed this line /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock to
>   var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock but no luck.
>
> /var/run/php directory in server contains php7.3-fpm.pid and
>   php7.3-fpm.sock.

and I think that php5.6 exists in the server because /etc/php/5.6 folder exitst in the server.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://askubuntu.com/a/927131/1012290) answer helped me.

I installed php5.6 fpm to server

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm
```

and in laravel forge I edited this line fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock; to fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock; in the website nginx configuration file.

SO phpinfo it changed to php5.6.

Answer (score 0):

You need install php-5 on your webserver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm
```

The link [php ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)